# For three numbers $a, b, \& c$––what numbers $x, y, \& z$ satisfy $bz + cy = 1, az + cx = 1, \& ay + bx = 1$? (in terms of $a, b, \& c$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm working on a 3D non-standard number system that doesn't form a field or ring. In this system, a number (represented $\{a, b, c\}$) has an additive inverse. Multiplication, ($\{a, b, c\} * \{x, y, z\} = \{bz + cy, az + cx, ay + bx\}$) however, is very strange in its properties. Currently, I am trying to figure out whether or not a number has a multiplicative inverse in this system.

$a, b, \& c$ are all real numbers, and addition is defined as $\{a, b, c\} + \{x, y, z\} = \{a + x, b + y, c + z\}$. The additive identity is $\{0, 0, 0\}$, and the additive inverse is $\{-a, -b, -c\}$. No multiplicative identity exists due to the definition of multiplication in this system.

Some trivial cases are that $\{0, 0, 0\} * \{x, y, z\}$ is always $\{0, 0, 0\}$––meaning that in this system (as in most systems) the multiplicative inverse of $\{0, 0, 0\}$ (written $0$ for simplicity) does not make sense. Moreover, $\{1, 1, 1\} * \{1, 1, 1\} = \{2, 2, 2\}$––meaning that $1$ is it's own multiplicative inverse. In fact, $\{n, n, n\} * \{n, n, n\} = \{2n^2, 2n^2, 2n^2\}$.

In summary, for arbitrary "$u$," can a number "$v = 1/u$" be defined such that "$u * v = \{n, n, n\}$."

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Working examples is an obvious place to start.  Not sure why you call that "$1$" by the way.  After all, $(1,1,1)*(1,1,1)=(2,2,2)$ so it's not a multiplicative identity.

Comment: Note:  you should also edit for clarity.  You never said what sort of things $a,b,c$ were.  Are they integers, rationals, reals, something else?  And you speak of an additive inverse, but you don't tell us how addition is defined.  Really, your post is extremely vague.

Comment: I'll add that information. I call it "1" for simplicity of writing, though you are correct that (and this is the reason the system doesn't form a ring) no multiplicative identity exists. There's a good chance that the simplest form of a multilicative inverse (if it exists) will not result in {1, 1, 1}––so I'll change the question a bit.

Comment: Please edit your question. Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why call it a multiplicative inverse?  There seems to be nothing special about multiplying to get $(1,1,1)$.  Anyway, you have three linear equations in three unknowns so there will be a unique solution unless the determinant is $0$, so just work out that determinant to get a key condition.  If the determinant is $0$ then you'll either have no solutions or infinitely many, but I'd exclude those cases personally.

Comment: @lulu I'm calling it a multiplicative inverse because I want to define a construct of divison, wherein $u ÷ v = u * 1/v$, similar to how one can define the construct of subtraction such that $u - v = u + (-v)$. The reason I need something that multiplies to get {1, 1, 1} is so that division will have the property $u ÷ u = 1$, which requires that $u * 1/u = 1$. That's how I derived the desired behaviour for the unary operation $1/u$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a linear system of equations, which we can analyse with standard methods.

The equations are:

$$\begin{eqnarray} by + cz & = & 1 \\
cx + az & = & 1 \\
bx + ay & = & 1 \end{eqnarray}$$

which in matrix notation is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b & c \\ c & 0 & a \\ b & a & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

The system is definitely invertible if the determinant of the matrix on the left is non-zero, which is fairly easy to calculate and comes to $a(b^2+c^2)$, which is zero only when either $a = 0$ or $b^2+c^2 = 0$ (which, assuming real numbers only, is equivalent to $b = c = 0$). You can invert the matrix any number of ways to get exact expressions for $x, y, z$.

We also need to check what happens when the matrix is not invertible.

**Case 1**: $a = 0$

The system becomes:

$$\begin{eqnarray} by + cz & = & 1 \\
cx & = & 1 \\
bx & = & 1 \end{eqnarray}$$

Clearly, we have $x = \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{b}$, so the system has zero solutions if $b \neq c$ or if $b = c = 0$. If $b = c$, then $by + cz = b(y + z) = 1$, and so $y + z = \frac{1}{b}$, and any pair of $y, z$ that satisfy this equation provides a solution.

**Case 2**: $b = c = 0$

The first equation here becomes $0 = 1$, and so there are clearly no solutions.

Comment: OP may have changed it since, but $by+cz$ should be $bz+cy$